# post form with jquery and open in new window

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have one page with jquery and two text boxes

i have one button with following script

```
  <input name="text1" type="text" id="text1" />
   <input name="text2" type="text" id="text2" />

<A class="floatRight button buttonAction3" href="#" name="save" id="save">Send</A>
```

i want a Jquery script to load send.php

on above button click

and data of both text boxes will be send as post

and send.php will open in new window with specified width and high

actually i dont want to process data using $.post.

what i want is open new window with

```
window.open()
```

and then open a php file in that window with post data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer to your question would be to use a form and add a target="_blank" attribute to it, this doesn't give you control of the width and height, though.

However, I think you should change how you approach this situation. This approach will make extending it a huge pain in the ass. Make use of s. jQuery can handle forms much easier than random input elements throughout the page.

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="send.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="25">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="bill@stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Now we can do:

```
  // Sweet, the form was submitted...
  $('#search').submit(function(e){

    // Let's get the form with jQuery...
    $form = $(this);

    // Now you can do things like...
    $.post( $form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray(), function( result ) {
        // "result" will inclue whatever the script returns...
    });

    // If you really need to open up the new window the only way I can think of controlling the size is with a get request...
    window.open( $form.attr('action') + '?' + $form.serialize(), 'PopUp', 'width=100,height=100' );

    // Stop the browsers default behavoir from kicking in!
    e.preventDefault()


});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("send.php", { text1 : $("#text1").val(), text2 : $("#text2").val() },
              function(html) {
                  // open new window here
              }
    });
});
```

Given that your elements are not wrapped in a form, the above should suffice. Explanation:

- Bind a click handler to the save button. Prevent the default 'action' of the link using `e.preventDefault()`.
- Post the two values of the text inputs using jQuery's `$.post` high-level ajax method.
- send.php will receive a $_POST array which looks like `array("text1" => "thetext", "text2" => "thetext")`
- The success callback function to `$.post` triggers once the server has sent its response back to the client. That's where you will want to open your new window.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: first of all this needs two times to click link , second what will be new window load code as i use window.open("page.php",null,"height=500,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes"); but where will be post variables